# What does . .bashrc actually do?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, terminal, bashrc

When I enter a eg. a new alias into my `.bashrc` file I can't use it in that terminal window immediately and until recently I thought I had to restart the terminal to reload the `.bashrc` file. Then I found out somewhere that if I write

```
. .bashrc
```

this will reload the `.bashrc` file in the current window and I don't have to restart. This works fins but what is actually happening? Why does this reload the `.bashrc` file?

Comment: With `.`, you "source" the file. Meaning it is being executed basically

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does source do?](http://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do)

Comment: @DanD. while the answer is the same, the question sounds quite distinct to me.

Comment: @Dan D. this question is more about the mening of **.** . Up until now I always thought about **.** as a shorthand for the current directory and .. as a shorthand for the parent directory. I never realised **.** was an alias for source (which in turn was a completely new concept for me).

If someone comes here and wants to know the difference I found [What is the difference between executing a bash script and sourcing a bash script?](http://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-and-sourcing-a-bash-scrip) to be very helpfull.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because `.` is a command.

It's a shell built-in command, that reads the named file and executes the commands therein in the current shell process.

The Bourne Again shell also has `source` as a synonym for this command.  But this is a Bashism (that the Bourne Again shell took from the C Shell).  Albeit it is a Bashism that the Bourne Again shell shares with the TENEX C Shell, the Z Shell, and others (but not the Korn shell, note).  The Single UNIX Specification only standardizes `.`.

Also note that the behaviour of `.`/`source` subtly changes dependent from whether the Bourne Again shell is being run in its POSIX-compatible mode or not.  (Again this is like other shells, although their non-standard behaviours are not the same as one another's.  With the Z Shell, for example, there is a precompiled shell script mechanism, and `source` subtly differs from `.` in its search path handling.  The Korn shell's `.` will run shell functions, for another example.)

`~/.bashrc` is merely one of several files whose contents are (dependent from how the shell process is invoked) *automatically sourced* at shell startup.  There's nothing prohibiting it from being *manually* sourced.  Although if its actions aren't idempotent, you might have some fixup work to do afterwards.

### Further reading

- ["Special Built-In Utilities: dot"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot).  *Shell Command Language*.  Single UNIX Specification.  Issue 6.
  IEEE 1003.1.  2013.  The Open Group.
- *[bashisms](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism)*.  Greg's wiki.
- ["Bourne shell builtins"](http://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html).  *Bash Reference Manual*.  Free Software Foundation.
- ["Bash builtins"](http://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html).  *Bash Reference Manual*.  Free Software Foundation.
- ["Bash Startup Files"](http://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html).  *Bash Reference Manual*.  Free Software Foundation.
- [What is the difference between executing a Bash script vs sourcing it?](https://superuser.com/questions/176783/)

Answer (score 1):

`help .` would tell you:

> `.: . filename [arguments]`
>
> ```
> Execute commands from a file in the current shell.
>
> Read and execute commands from FILENAME in the current shell.  The
> entries in $PATH are used to find the directory containing FILENAME.
> If any ARGUMENTS are supplied, they become the positional parameters
> when FILENAME is executed.
>
> Exit Status:
> Returns the status of the last command executed in FILENAME; fails if
> FILENAME cannot be read.
> ```

Saying `. .bashrc` executes (sources) the file `.bashrc` which makes the changes made to the file available in the current session.

By default, `~/.bashrc` would be read at login.

`.` is a synonym for `source`.

Answer (score 1):

The `.` command is the same thing as the `source` command, which executes your `.bashrc` file. This adds all the aliases you have defined and any other shell settings/variables into the current environment.
From `source`'s help page:

```
source: source filename [arguments]
    Execute commands from a file in the current shell.
```