# How to prevent "source" in a bash script from passing the script's arguments?

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, script

These questions address the functionality of `source`:
[What is the difference between executing a Bash script vs sourcing it?](https://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-and-sourcing-a-bash-scrip)
[What does 'source' do?](https://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do)

but I'm confused as to why calling `source` in a script passes the script's arguments. E.g. I have these 2 scripts:

*caller.sh*

```
source sourced.sh
source sourced.sh ""
```

*sourced.sh*

```
echo [$*]
```

When I do

```
./caller.sh arg1 arg2
```

I get

```
[arg1 arg2]
[]
```

"arg1 arg2" are passed to sourced.sh even though I didn't specify `source sourced.sh $*`.

Why?

I found that appending "" prevents the arguments from being passed. Is this the recommended way to prevent arguments passed?

Comment: _"..The ability to source a script with arguments is a bashism.."_ [Check here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5027/66388) for more details.

Answer (score 6):

`source` allows you to execute a command in the [current context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_%28command%29) (arguments `$*` are [part of context](http://ss64.com/bash/source.html)).

The second `source` call overwrites these arguments. Note it overwrites them only for the call, they are restored right after.

Comment: Thanks, Amessihel. Is the second call the recommended way to omit the arguments?

Comment: If you want to execute this command to a new context (only _exported_ variables will be accessible), better run it without `source`. Else, I don't know if there is a good practice to prevent this bash specific behaviour... Yours seems fine.

Comment: I need to use `source` because the real sourced.sh sets some env variables (and I can't modify it to export them as it's a published file).

Comment: If you know what variables you need, you can also pass them this way : `VAR=VAL VAR2=VAL2 sourced.sh` instead of source.