# how to know which SHELL is currently running?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

While I was referring to usage of **SOURCE** in linux, I got to know that from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do) **source** executes the command in current shell and **"./"** will execute in new shell.

My question is how do we know in which shell the commands are getting executed ?

Comment: The confusion arise when I saw the terms current shell and new shell. I am just checking how to check the current and new shell. May be the same query could be posted in different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most (if not all) shells on Linux provide you with the `$SHELL` environment variable:

```
mtak@frisbee:~$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

It's still a better practice to run with `./` and provide a shell in the script you're running (that's in the first line starting with `#!`). This way you get more consistent results.