# Exit command that doesn't result in 'Process Complete'?

Tags: bash, bash-scripting, osx-yosemite

I see that `exit 1` in a shell script results in the 'Process complete' message, causing the shell to become unresponsive. Is there a way to use the `exit` command and return to a prompt? I don't want to have to open a new session, but I don't see another way.

Edit: I use `.` but I get the same result with `source` as well

Comment: Is this "`exit 1` in a shell script" in a script you source? (with `source` or `.`).

Comment: When you run a script with `.` or `source`, it runs in the current shell. In your case, that means it's running in your interactive shell. When it exits, it exits *your interactive shell*. You need to either run it normally (as a subprocess) (note that running it with `./scriptname` instead of `. scriptname` will do this, provided it's executable and has a proper shebang), or have it use `return` instead of `exit`.

Answer (score 1):

Please see [*What does `source` do?*](https://superuser.com/a/46146/432690)

> `source` is a bash shell built-in command that executes the content of the file passed as argument, ***in the current shell***. It has a synonym in `.` (period).

`exit` in a sourced script makes the current shell exit, as if you typed `exit`. A scripts that is meant to be sourced should never `exit` its main shell (i.e. not a subshell) because its main shell is the shell you source the script from. Unless you know what you're doing and `exit` in a sourced script is really what you want.

You can `return` from a sourced script. If you need to source the script then `return 1` may be the right thing instead of `exit 1`.

A script that is not meant to be sourced should not be sourced. If it invokes `exit` in its main shell then it's most likely meant to be *executed*. Another useful link: [*What is the difference between sourcing (`.` or `source`) and executing a file in bash?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43882/108618)

So how to execute?

A command `bash scriptname` will run a separate `bash` process that will parse `scriptname` and execute its lines. If there is `exit` then it will exit the separate `bash`, not your current shell.

To be able to execute a script directly (like `./scriptname` instead of `bash scriptname`) you need a proper shebang as the first line of the script, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

and the file needs to be executable (`chmod +x scriptname`) and the filesystem holding the file must not be mounted with `noexec` option.